# How to populate jQuery Autocomplete form with non-hardcoded data?

Tags: jquery

I have a form here that I can get to autocomplete with hard-coded items in the problem-categories text field: http://www.problemio.com/add_problem.php by using this jquery code:

```
$("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    // Have to load stuff from db.
    source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"]
});
```

What I am not sure how to do is to construct it using category names returned by making an ajax call.  Could someone help explain the flow or post some pseudo-code for how this is usually done?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote), which even includes three examples of this.

> Autocomplete can be customized to work with various data sources, by
>   just specifying the source option. A data source can be:
>
> - an Array with local data
> - a String, specifying a URL
> - a Callback
>
> The local data can be a simple Array of Strings, or it contains
>   Objects for each item in the array, with either a label or value
>   property or both. The label property is displayed in the suggestion
>   menu. The value will be inserted into the input element after the user
>   selected something from the menu. If just one property is specified,
>   it will be used for both, eg. if you provide only value-properties,
>   the value will also be used as the label.
>
> When a String is used, the Autocomplete plugin expects that string to
>   point to a URL resource that will return JSON data. It can be on the
>   same host or on a different one (must provide JSONP). The request
>   parameter "term" gets added to that URL. The data itself can be in the
>   same format as the local data described above.
>
> The third variation, the callback, provides the most flexibility, and
>   can be used to connect any data source to Autocomplete. The callback
>   gets two arguments:
>
> - A request object, with a single property called "term", which refers to the value currently in the text input. For example, when the
>     user entered "new yo" in a city field, the Autocomplete term will
>     equal "new yo".
> - A response callback, which expects a single argument to contain the data to suggest to the user. This data should be filtered based on the
>     provided term, and can be in any of the formats described above for
>     simple local data (String-Array or Object-Array with label/value/both
>     properties). It's important when providing a custom source callback to
>     handle errors during the request. You must always call the response
>     callback even if you encounter an error. This ensures that the widget
>     always has the correct state.
>
> The label is always treated as text, if you want the label to be
>   treated as html you can use Scott González' html extension. The demos
>   all focus on different variations of the source-option - look for the
>   one that matches your use case, and take a look at the code.